# AngularJS Change colourscheme thoughout different pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 buttons on the main page, blue purple and red. (In a simple `<button></button>`) How would i go about making it so that the buttons will change the colour of the rest of the pages?

For example. the current colour scheme on the site is red. But i would like it so then when the blue button is pressed, everything that was red goes blue.

***Edit***

So heres what i did using the examples below

```
<button ng-click="changeTheme(blue)" class="btn btn-info">Blue</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);
    app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.theme = 'blue  ';
      $scope.changeTheme = function(theme) {
        $scope.theme = theme;
      }
    });
    </script>
    <style>
      .red btn btn-info{
        background-color: red;
      }
      .blue btn btn-info{
        background-color: blue;
      }
    </style>
```

This is one button, ITs supposed to change the colour of the button to a blue button(the button below this comment), Any ideas what i did wrong?

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
      <div ng-app="app" ng-class="theme" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <a ui-sref="package" class="btn btn-block btn-info">
            Choose Package &nbsp <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is some what unclear where each code element is located and in what relationship to each other they are. May be it would be helpfull if you insert a working code snippet using the stackoverflow snippet feature...

Comment: I've placed them all in the same page,  the package buttons at the bottom and the other buttons at the other buttons at the top of the page.

Comment: why 2 spaces after blue on this line : `$scope.theme = 'blue  ';` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could switch a CSS class on the root of the DOM.

To do this you could use ng-class to bind the CSS class of an element:

```
<div ng-class="theme">
```

this will bind the class to the property *theme* in the elements scope.
The content of *theme* then can be changed just as you need.

Example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.theme = 'red';
  $scope.changeTheme = function(theme) {
    $scope.theme = theme;
  }
});
```

```css
.red label {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue label {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-class="theme">
  <label>Some Text</label>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <button ng-click="changeTheme('red')">Red</button>
  <button ng-click="changeTheme('blue')">Blue</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually! now i've put it into test its not working, Let me update my code to show you quickly what i did and you can let me know where ive gone wrong? Thanks?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code on how you could do it :

```
<div ng-class={{colorScheme}}>

    <button ng-click="colorScheme = 'red'">ColorScheme Red</button>
    <button ng-click="colorScheme = 'blue'">ColorScheme Blue</button>
    <button ng-click="colorScheme = 'green'">ColorScheme Green</button>

    <p>Awesome content</p>

</div>
```

css:

```
.red { background-color: red; }
.red p { /*whatever*/ }

.blue { background-color: blue; }
.blue p { /*whatever*/ }

.green { background-color: green; }
.green p { /*whatever*/ }
```

Comment: Sorry its not background its the button colour and navbar etc

Comment: I've updated my answer but basically once you have the css parent class edited, you can modify every child element css.